# Difference size font rendering on Windows VS MacOS. How to solve?

Tags: css, fonts

I've been wondering myself why on windows my font looks smaller, and much crappier than on OSX.

Screenshot Mac VS Windows : http://screencast.com/t/UUxqLRhM

Is that because i used "em" on some rules instead of "px" ?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it has to do with how the different operating systems handle font smoothing. The short version of the story is that Windows alters the fonts slightly to make them more readable, but in some cases it actually makes the font look way worse. What version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 7. But it looks way smaller than the OSX version, not sure the aliasing has all the blame here.

Comment: It's just the lowercase letters that look smaller. The numbers are the same height. (Confirmed with an on-screen ruler.) Microsoft's font rendering engine tries to differentiate lowercase and capital letters more than usual.

Comment: So shall I increase the size of the font to make it readable on windows ? Or is there any other viable options ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This is from a comment, but I'll post as an answer.)

This is nothing on your end, and the culprit is different font rendering engines. Mac OS X tries to render fonts exactly as they were designed, whereas Windows tries to alter them slightly to make them more readable. The problem is, with certain fonts and sizes, it actually makes them look worse. ([This article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html) is a good read on the subject.)

If you make the font bigger, it will probably make it look better on Windows. I would venture to say that if you removed the bold font-weight, it would also look cleaner. You could also try a different font.

Overall though, all you can do is just play with different settings and see what looks good and what doesn't; the actual rendering is out of your control.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers do have different standard font-sizes. Maybo other font-types and the different way to show fonts of the OS. 
100% same look is... not possible

Answer (score 0):

The way MAC and PC handle fonts is different, but that is not what is happening here. You have set a font that is not web-safe, "MyHelveticaBold", and the font windows is using is clearly not the same as the one on your Mac. If you don't want to use a [web-safe font](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) then you should use [open source web fonts](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/) that you can serve to the user upon visiting.

There are some CSS properties that can adjust how a font is rendered such as -webkit-font-smoothing. Read more here: http://blog.typekit.com/2011/01/26/css-properties-that-affect-type-rendering/