# Why does my website display different on a PC than a Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome

I'm at a loss as to why my website ([violetoeuvre.com](http://violetoeuvre.com)) display differently on a PC than on a Mac. It might be plausible if I was using different browsers, but I'm using Chrome in both cases.

I can't figure out why Emma Carmichael and the navigation at the top (Writing, Blog, Contact) is a little above the black on the PC, but bleeds into the white on a Mac (what i want).

Mac:https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgYHw.jpg 
PC: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH5TR.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: As a matter of fact, you're using different browsers : chrome for mac and chrome for PC...

Comment: Is there a live URL or code we can look at?  Even though you're using the "same" browser it is different in someways.   There may be some css that you are using that could be adjusted....

Comment: Are your screen sizes the same? Do they have the same resolution? Are the chrome settings the same for both computers? Do they both have the same color spectrum?

Comment: Might be a duplicate question for the font aspect : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530183/difference-size-font-rendering-on-windows-vs-macos-how-to-solve

Comment: @Jason - sorry, violetoeuvre.com

Answer (score 1):

Are the images randomized?  They are two different images shown.  Is there a chance on is a chance one has a cached version with different CSS / HTML?

How about posting the code for the page - maybe someone will know the intricacies of mac vs pc in chrome with respect to the elements you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I guess issue is with height of black section.
try giving height of black section in %.
That might work!!
Hope it helps.